# Get return value of worker.onmessage inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, return, memoization

I have created a Caching (Memoized) function which takes another function as a parameter

The following is the function which is being cached. The function utilises a worker. The issue here is that if 
**var hello = GetSubRegion(1233)** ,then hello is undefined because the function inside onmessage returns a value but not the parent GetSubRegion function.

```
function GetSubRegion(selectedMainRegion){
if (typeof(subRegWorker) != "undefined") {
subRegWorker.terminate();
}
subRegWorker = new Worker("subRegWorker.js");
subRegWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
var workData = e.data;
jQuery("#_sub_region").html(workData);
subRegWorker.terminate();
return workData;
}
var result = subRegWorker.postMessage(selectedMainRegion);
return result;
}
```

The following is the caching function. Due to the above issue, there is no value returned for 
**let result = fun(n)** , and hence nothing is cached.

```
function memoizer(fun){
    let cache = {}
    return function (n){
        if (cache[n] != undefined ) {
          return cache[n]
        } else {
        console.log(n);
          let result = fun(n)
          cache[n] = result
          return result
        }
    }
}
```

How to solve this ?

The following is how I am calling the cached function.

```
jQuery("#_main_region").change(function() {
var getCacheSub = memoizer(GetSubRegion);
var inputMainRegion = jQuery('#_main_region').find(":selected").val();
getCacheSub(inputMainRegion);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caching issue was solved as follows, the changed code is market as comment -

```
    var cache = {};
    function memoizer(fun){
        
        return function (n){
            if (cache[n] != undefined ) {
            jQuery("#_sub_region").html(cache[n]);  // This was changed
            return cache[n]
            } else {
            console.log(n);
              cache[n] = result
              return result
            }
        }
    }
```

```
function GetSubRegion(selectedMainRegion){
if (typeof(subRegWorker) != "undefined") {
subRegWorker.terminate();
}
subRegWorker = new Worker("subRegWorker.js");
subRegWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
var workData = e.data;
cache[n] = workData // This was changed
jQuery("#_sub_region").html(workData);
subRegWorker.terminate();
return workData;
}
subRegWorker.postMessage(selectedMainRegion);
}
```